# How to open shared folder within xp?

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, shared-folders

Can you describe me how to view files on xp machine after i made shared folder based on [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/116309/use-ubuntus-public-folder-to-easily-share-files-between-computers/)

browser method preferable

Answer (score 0):

What you did was enabled sharing of your files in Ubuntu, whereas you need to enable sharing in your Windows OS to be able to reach it.